# Rails and jquery colorbox

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, colorbox

I try to display in popup html page after click on link:

```
<%= link_to 'click me', new_site_path, :class=>'colorbox' %>
```

My JS:

```
$(".colorbox").colorbox({ href:"/invitations/new.html" });
```

or

```
$(".colorbox").colorbox();
```

But it always  show not only this new.html page, but also elements from whole application.html.erb

When I look in firebug I see that #cboxLoadedContent have all css, js, metatags  of page ... it put all page inside this div

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `new_site_path` routes to `SitesController#new` you can do this

```
SitesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    ...existing code...
    render :layout => false
  end
end
```

or

```
SitesController < ApplicationController
  layout false, only: :new
end
```